# Get the non unique values from 2 columns using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need in getting the non unique values (no duplicates) between Column A and B and reflect it on Column C. I need this in a formula coz it will be used for a google sheet and macros don't translate well to it.

What I'm doing is checking if Column B has any duplicates in Column A and if it has, it will not be reflected in column C. 
I've tried using `=iferror(vlookup(B2,A2:A50,1,0),B2)` but it will also reflect the non error values.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to Do with VBA using an UDF. However, just with native Excel functions the best I can come up with is using a helper column (which you can of course hide afterwards). 
[image: Uniques without VBA]

On column C use this only show the values from column B that are not in column A.
`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2;$A$2:$A$50;0));IF(B2<>"";B2;"");"")`

Then on column D use this to only show the unique values for column C.
`=IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C;SMALL(INDEX((($C$2:$C$50)<>"")*ROW($C$2:$C$50);0);ROW(C1)+COUNTBLANK($C$2:$C$50)));"")`
(Not my original work, don't know who came up with it first though.)

**Remember to replace ; with , in the formulas.**

Basically all this does is shows the results of column C without blanks. If someone manages to merge these functions that would be awesome.

Comment: This actually worked. Thanks and I agree, if someone can manage these two, it would be awesome.